# 16 bytes-long integer types

Tags: c++, types, 64-bit

I'm compiling a C++ program using GCC on 64bits - machine/OS/ (with `-m64` option passed to `g++`). As expected, `sizeof(long double) == 16` – I'm wondering whether there is 16 bytes-long standard type for integers?

P.S. `__int128_t` is an artificial extension that emulates standard type as I understood. Other than that I didn't find anything.

Comment: `long double` isn't actually a 16-byte type. It probably uses 10 bytes to store the value, and the remainder is padding to make it 8-byte aligned.

Comment: @Kerrek Is there a way to find out an exact size of the type then, i.e. how big can be the number that I can store in this type?

Comment: The `<limits>` traits are probably your best way to make portable statements about available ranges.

Comment: [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/995714)

Comment: [`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) can be 12 or 16 bytes in x86 gcc depending on which of [`-m96bit-long-double` and `-m128bit-long-double`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html) is selected, but the real content is only 80 bits, the remaining are just padding. On MSVC and many compilers it's exactly the same as 64-bit double. It may also be double-double, IBM extended double or IEEE-754 quadruple precision https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Ieee128PowerPC. No guarantee about it being 16 bytes either

Answer (score 3):

Nope, only guaranteed sizes are for `char`, `unsigned char` & `signed char`, and they are `1`:

**5.3.3 Sizeof [expr.sizeof]**

> 1 The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression,
>   which is not evaluated, or a parenthesized type-id. The sizeof
>   operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or
>   incomplete type, or to an enumeration type before all its enumerators
>   have been declared, or to the parenthesized name of such types, or to
>   an lvalue that designates a bit-field. **sizeof(char), sizeof(signed
>   char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1. The result of sizeof applied to
>   any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is implementation-defined.** [ Note:
>   in particular, sizeof(bool) and sizeof(wchar_t) are
>   implementation-defined.74) —end note ] [ Note: See 1.7 for the
>   definition of byte and 3.9 for the definition of object
>   representation. —end note ]

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I thought `long long` was guaranteed to have 64-bits?

Comment: @Rapptz not according to the standard.

Comment: I thought so too (about long long).

Comment: @Rapptz It's guaranteed to have _at least_ 64 bits.

Comment: To meet the minimum requirements of the C standard, `long long` must be _at least_ 64 bits long; it does not have to be exactly 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

The c++ standard does not standardize the size of each type (accept char) but the difference in size in relation to each other.

```
A char has to be 1 byte.
A short has to be >= to a char.
An int has to be >= to a short.
A long has to be >= to an int.
and a long long has to be >= to a long.
```

same goes for float types.

I believe most compilers now support up to 8-byte integers

however I know for a fact some, if not most don't have 16-byte integers.

I also think that there are some object classes/structs that people have developed to emulate a 16-byte integer that would work on most compilers.